# CircleCI protractor tests timeout with onPrepare function using google oauth ServiceLogin

Tags: angularjs, oauth, webdriver, protractor, circleci

App is Firebase, Express, Angular, using angular-fullstack generator

In the application, auth is handled by angularfire's $authWithOAuthRedirect.
In the protractor tests, I use onPrepare to pre-auth a test user:

```
onPrepare: function() {
  browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
  browser.driver.get('https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin');
  browser.driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60000);
  browser.driver.findElement(By.id('Email')).sendKeys(USER);
  browser.driver.findElement(By.id('Passwd')).sendKeys(PASS);
  browser.driver.findElement(By.id('signIn')).click();
  browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
  browser.driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3000);
}
```

This works great on my workstation.  But in CircleCI...
Even with obscenely large wait times (like the 60000 here), the e2e tests timeout.  And different parts of the tests time out randomly, even if I just re-run the build.

I've had to disable my e2e tests in circle.yml, which is not a particularly good solution.

Any suggestions?  Workaround ideas?

Comment: Those are some HUGE timeout you have set. Plus, what is the exact stacktrace look like? NoSuchElement exception?

Comment: And, seems like a Captcha issue to me